# Response.StatusCode and Internet Explorer - Display custom message?

Tags: asp.net, http, internet-explorer-7

I am implementing a HttpRequestValidationException in my Application_Error Handler, and if possible, I want to display a custom message.

Now, I'm thinking about the StatusCode. In my current example, it sends a 200, which I think should not be done. I would like to send the (IMHO) more appropriate 400 Bad Request instead. However, at the same time, I would like to use Response.Write to enter a custom message. Firefox displays it properly, but IE7 gives me the Default unhelpful Internet Explorer Error Page.

On one side, I guess that Internet Explorer just assumes that everything <> 200 is simply not having any "good" content, and the [RFC is not really clear](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.1) here.

So I just wonder, is sending a HTTP 200 for an Error Page caused by a HttpRequestValidationException good practice or not? Are there good alternatives?

Comment: Thanks! My solution: I created an >512 Byte Error.aspx, but by Global.asax will set the StatusCode to 400 and then do a Server.Transfer instead of Response.Redirect. Works well with AJAX and Internet Explorer.

Comment: Just to add: Normally, a Response.Redirect would also be a viable solution. However, if you use ASP.net AJAX, you will also be redirected. Server.Transfer does allow you to stay on the current Page for AJAX-Requests and handle the error in JavaScript. See my HttpRequestValidationException question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An HTTP 200 Response Code does not indicate an error.  It indicates that everything was OK.  You should not use a 200 response code for an error.

Internet Explorer shows its "Friendly Errors" page if the response is less than 512 bytes.  Here's more on this issue: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx,

Comment: Good to know, so one fix would be to blow up the response to at least 513 bytes which should be doable.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's certainly not a good practice. 2XX status codes mean (among other things) that the **request is valid**. Which is just the contrary to raising a HttpRequestValidationException.

I don't know how to make IE behave correctly, sadly. A slightly better way than to send a 200 would be to redirect it to an error page, but still far from perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer shows what they call a "friendly HTTP error message" when the response is 4xx or 5xx. This option can be turned off by the user in IE's Tools.Options.Advanced[Browsing] dialog.

Sending a 200 for an error page is generally bad practice. One alternative would be to have a valid "Error" page that's *supposed* to show error messages (so a 200 would be okay) and then use a 3xx redirect to that page.

Comment: That actually sounds like a good idea. I'm already getting nightmares thinking how to get that mechanism work with AJAX, but i'll fight through that because i'm not happy with my current Response.Write(hardcoded html) approach, as a separate error.aspx has other advantanges.